# Alter table add new field "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `megssage`(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I would like to add new column as `time_updated` with default value "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE `megssage` 
   CHANGE `time_updated` `time_updated` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT  ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

But I am getting an error. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 25):

If you want to add a field to the **`megssage`** table:

```
ALTER TABLE `megssage` ADD time_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE `megssage` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `time_updated` `time_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Comment: Worked great for adding the `ON UPDATE` to an existing column!

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
ALTER TABLE `megssage` ADD `TIME_UPDATED` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL AFTER `time_create`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `megssage` 
ADD time_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.